# how to have multiple axes in plotly.js for 3D chart

Tags: javascript, plotly, scatter3d

I want to do something similar than here https://plot.ly/javascript/multiple-axes/ but for 3D charts.
For instance keep x and y unchanged and have 2 z-scales for 2 different frames.
I've seen that "scene" can have different instance but I'm not sure we use scene and scene2 in one unique chart... (I tried without success)

If someone has an idea, I'll be grateful!